# Terminal app in Mac OS X Lion 10.7 stuck?

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal

Some days ago I tried to create a shell script which would open all the torrents files in my downloads folder. I am not sure if I get the sh file written right, since then I am getting this message:

```
Last login: Fri May 18 22:54:28 on ttys000
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Users/Alex/Downloads/(Demonoid.me)-Adobe_Master_Collection_CS5_(OS_X)__12302562.8934.torrent
with error -10810 for the files
/Users/Alex/Downloads/Coda_1_6_2_[_Plist]_[Serial]_O-Demonoid.me-O_12302562.8934.torrent,
/Users/Alex/Downloads/Coda_1_7_3_[k'd]-((Demonoid.me))_12302562.8934.torrent,
/Users/Alex/Downloads/[kat.ph]grid.systems.in.graphic.design.josef.muller.brockmann.torrent,
and /Users/Alex/Downloads/[kat.ph]pixie.lott.cry.me.out.mp3.housezz.torrent.
job done
/bin/bash: line 8: end: command not found
```

[Process completed]

And I can't do anything in Terminal. I don't know what to do. Any insights about it?

Comment: Close the terminal and open a new one? Or maybe try the `reset` command?

Comment: every new window I open I get the same message, I remembered a copy a sh file to the /bin folder

Answer (score 7):

- Open a terminal and let it hang.
- Open the terminal preferences menu (Command-comma).
- In the Startup tab, remember your current shell setting.
- Choose a shell other than Bash or Sh (e.g. `/bin/tcsh` — this is a desparation measure, and only temporary).
- Close the locked terminal.
- Open a new terrminal (Command-N).
- That should give you a command prompt.
- In that window, edit your `.profile` or `.bashrc` or whatever you added the Torrent lines to.
- Remove the Torrent-related lines.
- Go back to terminal preferences.
- Reset the shell to `/bin/bash`.
- Try opening a terminal window once more.

When it comes to trying to add the Torrents again, write a shell script.  Debug it.  Only put it in your profile when you're sure it is correct, stable, reliable, and doesn't lock your terminal.  Then test it with a terminal already open — opening a new terminal to do the test.  You've then still got an unlocked terminal you can fix problems with.

If you have a graphical Vim (Gvim or MacVim), you may be able to launch that and then edit your `.profile` without having to tweak the Terminal preferences.

Comment: changing the terminal preferences works, thanks very much, now I can use another terminal, but I can't find either the .profile file or the .bashrc, is it supposed to be in my home folder?

Comment: Those are the normal places, but which file did you edit to add the Torrent startups?  Because that's the file you should edit again to remove the Torrent startups.  If you modified something in `/etc/`, go fix that.  In case of doubt, consider recovering from your Time Machine backups, or any other backup you have.  One of the options to `bash` is: _`--noprofile`
Don’t load the system-wide startup file `/etc/profile` or any of the personal initialization files `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` when Bash is invoked as a login shell._'

Comment: I think I added some lines to /bin/bash, because I used nano to open it, and I saw what I had wrote in the script written in that file…so I deleted it, now it works, but only if I put /bin/bash in the preferences panel as default startup, it says "shell opens with" but the option above, that won't work...

Comment: On my machine, `/bin/bash` is a universal binary for x84_64 and i386.  It is unlikely that you had to modify that, though anything is possible.  You won't see the effect of the changed file until you do reset the login shell in preferences and start a new terminal.

Comment: I am not sure but I guess it has to do with /usr/bin/login , I have deleted the preference plist terminal with no luck .

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done if you can't remember what you did.  You may be stuck with using `tcsh` from here on.  Or with creating a new account.  But it ought to be possible to fix it if you can remember what you changed to add the torrent stuff.

Comment: whenever I check the option in the preferences panel "Default login open", then I get the message "process completed", but if i change it to command complete path and enter /bin/sh or bash or tcsh , then it's fine

Comment: any way to repair the bash file? I am just a beginner in bash, think i messed it up

Comment: If you really modified `/bin/bash`, then your best hope is that you did not also mess up `/bin/sh`.  Use `file /bin/*sh` and check that `/bin/sh` is OK, and you can copy `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`.  On my Mac, there is 64 bytes difference in size, but `/bin/sh --version` reports it is `bash 3.2.48(1)`.  If yours does the same, the copy should fix things back up.  Otherwise, build your own new bash, or restore from a backup, or find a way to install it with `fink` or equivalent, or from the o/s media, or ... ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: /bin/sh is fine, in fact that's what I use, I just can't use bash if I set he terminal to start up with bash as my default shell. Are they same? Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: `/bin/sh` is also `bash`, yes.  So if you've damaged the `bash` executable, you should be able to copy `/bin/sh` over `/bin/bash` and the result should function as `bash`.